# count number of dots in property

Tags: ant

I've got two properties which represent version-numbers (like 1.0.2.4).
I need to compare whether one of the properties contains a dot more than the other ones.

What's the easiest way to achieve this in ANT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from Mark O'Connor should suffice. But a more pure (generic) Ant solution could look like this:

```
<macrodef name="getcount">
    <attribute name="valueToCheck" />
    <attribute name="propertyToSet" />
    <attribute name="characterToCount" />

    <sequential>
        <resourcecount property="@{propertyToSet}">
            <tokens>
                <stringtokenizer delims="@{characterToCount}" />
                <string value="@{valueToCheck}" />
            </tokens>
        </resourcecount>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

And could be used like:

```
<property name="version1" value="1.2.3.4" />
<property name="version2" value="1.2.3.4.5" />

<target name="init" depends="checkVersions" if="versions.are.different">
    <echo>versions differ!</echo>
</target>

<target name="checkVersions">
    <getcount valueToCheck="${version1}" propertyToSet="ver1.count" characterToCount="." />
    <getcount valueToCheck="${version2}" propertyToSet="ver2.count" characterToCount="." />

    <condition property="versions.are.different">
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${ver1.count}" arg2="${ver2.count}"></equals>
        </not>
    </condition>
</target>
```

*Keep in mind, since we're using delimiters, values like "1.2.3.4." wouldn't result in 5 but 4 because nothing is following the last delimiter.*

Comment: I like both answers but prefer this one because it is Ant only.

Answer (score 2):

Use a script condition to perform the test

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

   <property name="ver1" value="1.0.2.4"/>
   <property name="ver2" value="1.0.2"/>

   <condition property="ver1.has.more.dots">
      <scriptcondition language="javascript"><![CDATA[
      var count1 = String(project.getProperty("ver1")).split(".").length;
      var count2 = String(project.getProperty("ver2")).split(".").length;

      self.setValue(count1 > count2)
      ]]></scriptcondition>
   </condition>

   <target name="run" if="ver1.has.more.dots">
      <echo message="It works!"/>
   </target>

</project>
```